# XPath that selects table cells using wildcard

Tags: html, xpath, web

I am writing an XPath which targets the TD cells in an HTML table. It is written in such a way that I can select all cells in a row, select all cells in a column, or select an individual cell by providing a wildcard for either a row or column.

**XPath:**

`//*[@id='myGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[{index0}]/td[{index1}]`

**Cases:**

**Select first row:**
index0 = 1  index1 = * (BROKEN)

**Select first column:**
index0 = *  index1 = 1   (WORKS)

**Select top left cell:**
index0 = 1  index1 = 1   (WORKS)

The first case is omitting certain TDs (yellow cells indicate XPath selection):
[image: The first case is omitting certain TDs:]

The HTML structure for the divisions reveals that some TD's do not contain a 'span'. Not sure why this would prevent the TD from being selected, since the XPath targets TDs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XPath, `tr[*]` does **not** mean a `tr` at *any* index; it means a `tr` with any child element.

To select `tr` elements regardless of index position, omit the `[*]` predicate altogether.

Similar reasoning applies to `td[*]`.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that by using a period as the wild card, the XPath selects all divisions appropriately. Final xpath:

**Select all cells in first row:**
`//*[@id='myGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[.]`

**Select all cells in first column:**
`//*[@id='myGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[.]/td[1]`

**Select top left cell:**
`//*[@id='myGrid']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

[XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: You've gone from one misconception (that `tr[*]` means all `tr`) to another (that `tr[.]` means all `tr`) and ignored the actual explanation of how to select all `tr` (or `td`) elements.   If you drop your superfluous `[.]` predicate and use just `tr` and `td` for all such elements [***as I already recommended but you chose to ignore***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49930989/290085), you'd have a cleaner solution.  Understand the concepts, especially when presented with them directly, rather than just guess by trial and error.